# How to simulate daylight saving time transition in a unit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I have a code, that compare the last timestamp with the actual timestamp. If the actual timestamp is before the last timestamp, the systemtime has been manipulated. Because of the transition from or to daylight saving time, I work with UTC.
Now I would like to write an unit test for this special situation.

```
public void TransitionFromDSTToNonDST()
{
    var dayLightChangeEnd= TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetDaylightChanges(DateTime.Now.Year).End;
    var stillInDaylightSavingTime= dayLightChangeEnd.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(62));
    //stillInDaylightSavingTime.IsDaylightSavingTime() returns true
    //stillInDaylightSavingTime is 01.58 am
    var noDaylightSavingTimeAnymore= dayLightChangeEnd.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(32));
    //noDaylightSavingTimeAnymore.IsDaylightSavingTime() returns false
    //noDaylightSavingTimeAnymore is 02.28 am
}
```

But actually I would like to simulate the following:

```
var stillInDaylightSavingTime = //for example 02.18 am BEFORE switching to Non-DST
var noDaylightSavingTimeAnymore = //for example 02.10 am AFTER switching to Non-DST
```

So the question is how can I define that a 02.18 am is either DST or not.

Comment: If you are using UTC then you don't observe day light savings.

Comment: @Matthew: I know that. But I would like to write an unit test, to make sure the consistency check works. I would like to test the method without knowing that the method works internal with UTC.

Comment: Do you realize sntp and clock resets may mess with your results as well?  If you are doing something with a date value why don't you expose the time as a parameter to the method instead of expecting the method to call a static method/property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MSDN [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx):

> Conversion operations between time zones (such as between UTC and local time, or between one time zone and another) take daylight saving time into account, but arithmetic and comparison operations **do not**.

IMO you should add your minutes in UTC and then convert to local kind.

Here's the (updated) code:

```
var dayLightChangeEnd = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetDaylightChanges(DateTime.Now.Year).End.ToUniversalTime();
var stillInDaylightSavingTime = dayLightChangeEnd.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(62)).ToLocalTime();
Console.WriteLine(stillInDaylightSavingTime);
Console.WriteLine(stillInDaylightSavingTime.IsDaylightSavingTime());
var noDaylightSavingTimeAnymore = dayLightChangeEnd.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2)).ToLocalTime();
Console.WriteLine(noDaylightSavingTimeAnymore);
Console.WriteLine(noDaylightSavingTimeAnymore.IsDaylightSavingTime());
```

@WaltiD: I can't comment but the code above prints 02:58 before and after DST shift.

Comment: How can I add minutes in UTC? Like `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(62).ToUniversalTime().ToLocalTime()`? But the question is still: How to define if 02.18am of October 30th, 2011 is DST or not.

Comment: It turns out, I can comment, sry ;) See my example about adding.

Comment: It also prints 02:58 before and after DST shift.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I missed the end of the line.. `dayLightChangeEnd = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetDaylightChanges(DateTime.Now.Year).End.ToUniversalTime();` - ToUniversalTime() looks like the solution.

Comment: Also `ToLocal`s on printing ;)

Comment: And in fact it is not me, who should be voted up, but the exceptionally good MSDN documentation, where I found such information.

Answer (score -2):

If you are trying to tset static methods or properties you could look at PEX/Moles

- [Pex and Moles: Untestable Code? Not really.](http://angler.wordpress.com/2010/01/21/pex-and-moles-untestable-code-not-really/) (some random blog post)
- [PEX and Moles from MSR](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/)